# How to solve the recurrence $T(2k)+(2k-1)(2k-2)T(2k-2)=(-1)^{k-1}\cdot 2\cdot(2k-2)!$?

Tags: calculus

I have to solve the recurrence $T(2k)+(2k-1)(2k-2)T(2k-2)=(-1)^{k-1}\cdot 2\cdot(2k-2)!$ with $T(2)=2$.

I find this recurence when I tried to calculate $\left.[(\arctan{x})^2]^{(n)}\right|_{x=0}$ (the n-th derivative).

And I'm solving it as following:

$y=(\arctan{x})^2$

$(1+x^2)y'=2\arctan{x}$

then differentiate both sides for $2k$ times and $2k-1$ times respectively,  $y^{(2k+1)}(0)+2k(2k-1)y^{(2k-1)}(0)=0$ and $y^{(2k)}(0)+(2k-1)(2k-2)y^{(2k-2)}(0)=(-1)^{k-1}2\cdot(2k-2)!$.

Looking into $y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0)=2$, then we have

$y^{(2k-1)}(0)=0$.

But I don't have any idea to calculate the derivates of even orders, except calculate it one by one.

So my question is, how to solve the recurence or how to solve this problem in a wiser way.

===============================================

Now I re-calculate this problem using Leibniz formula, and my answer is

$T(2n+2)=(-1)^n 2(2n+1)!\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2k+1}$,

Putting $n=0,1,2$ my answer is excatly the value of $[(\arctan{x})^2]^{(2n+2)}$ at $x=0$.

And my answer contains $1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}$, so I believe I cannot improve the form without importing special function like $psi$ or any others.

Thanks for you all.

Comment: Here's a start: divide both sides by $(2k)!$, and make the substitution $U(2k)=\frac{T(2k)}{(2k)!}$.  Then the recurrence becomes $U(2k)+U(2k-2)=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(2k-1)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you want is
$(\arctan^2(x))^{(n)}$,
I have derived the formula for
$(\arctan(x))^{(n)}$
below.
Combined with
Leibnitz's formula
$(fg)^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}
$,
so
$(f^2)^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}f^{(n-k)}
$,
this can give a formula for this.

$x^2+1 = (x+i)(x-i)
$
so
$(x^2+1)^n = (x+i)^n(x-i)^n
$
so
$\dfrac1{(x^2+1)^n} = \dfrac1{(x+i)^n(x-i)^n}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{d^n \arctan(x)}{dx^n} 
&= \frac12 (n-1)!i (-1)^n ((-i + x)^{-n} - (i + x)^{-n})
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfy)}\\
&= \frac12 (n-1)!i (-1)^n \left(\dfrac1{(-i + x)^{n}} - \dfrac1{(i + x)^{n}}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)!i (-1)^n}{2(x^2+1)^n} \left(\dfrac{(x^2+1)^n}{(-i + x)^{n}} - \dfrac{(x^2+1)^n}{(i + x)^{n}}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)!i (-1)^n}{2(x^2+1)^n} \left((x+i)^n - (x-i)^n\right)\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)!i (-1)^n}{2(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k\binom{n}{k}(i^{n-k}-(-i)^{n-k})\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)!i (-1)^n}{2(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}(i^{k}-(-i)^{k})\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)! (-1)^n}{2(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2k+1 \le n} x^{n-(2k+1)}\binom{n}{2k+1}2((-1)^{k+1})
\qquad\text{(see below)}\\
&= \dfrac{ (n-1)! (-1)^n}{(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2k+1 \le n} x^{n-(2k+1)}\binom{n}{2k+1}(-1)^{k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

I'll stop here.

Here's the formula for
$i^k-(-i)^k$.

$i^k-(-i)^k
=0 (k=0),
=i-(-i) = 2i (k=1),
=i^2-(-i)^2=0 (k=2),
=i^3-(-i)^3=-2i (k=3)
$
so
$i(i^k-(-i)^k)
=0 (k=0, 2),
=-2, 2 (k=1, 3)
=2(-1)^{(k+1)/2} (k=1, 3)
$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

This recurrence equation making $2k=j\;$ is equivalent to

$$
T(j)+(j-2) (j-1) T(j-2)=-2 i^j (j-2)!
$$

with solution

$$
T(j) = -i^j (j+1)! \left(c_2 (-1)^j+c_1+(-1)^{2 j+1} \Phi (-1,1,j+1)+\psi ^{(0)}(j+1)\right)
$$

Comment: what is the $\psi$ and $\Phi$?

Comment: @闫嘉琦  $\psi^{(0)}\;$ is the PolyGamma(0,j+1) function and $\Phi$ is the LerchPhi(-1,1,j+1) function.